# Where did I get a dog?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I have a dog now. He's sitting in *The Odyssey* with his little hat on. Doesn't do much.

I'm pretty sure I didn't buy one of those, and there's no dog in my souvenir list. Where the heck did I get that? What's the trigger?

Comment: Alternate question title: “Why is there a dog in my spaceship?”

Comment: You can get the dog in Tostarena Town to follow you around after he finds the Moon for you.  Is it the same dog?

Comment: So it wasn't just me ignoring the story then.   Some other people also noticed the dog but don't remember why it's there.  I feel less crazy now.

Comment: @JAL: I was going to say no, but I checked, and it looks like the dog disappears from the Odyssey in kingdoms with a dog moon. That seems to imply it is the same dog following me around. (It's kind of weird, though, because one Toad's dialogue implies the dog in one of the kingdoms is their dog, not mine.) Dunno when the dog starts showing up in the Odyssey, though.

Comment: I believe it comes after you see it/play with it in the mushroom kingdom.

Comment: Follow-up question: why does the dog bark silently?

Answer (score 7):

From the [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Dog):
"the Dog appears inside the Odyssey after finishing the game at least once..."